# how can i set a background image in ios objective c to rootViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

i can set a background color like :
rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(35.0/255.0) green:(92.0/255.0) blue:(78.0/255.0) alpha:1];

how can i set in rootViewController an image background ?

Comment: As every View is build with Layers you can access those and add your image to its contents property with a bridged cast.

Comment: Why you not add Image UI to rootViewController.view and set image for that object. This way is simple for do the background on controller.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViews` are basically backed by `CALayer`'s so you can apply settings to its properties.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourAssetImage"];
rootViewController.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id)img.CGImage;
```